# error when using tikz with quotes and angles

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-angles

i want to draw some angles using tikz where i have the following code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
    \begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (c) at (0,1);
    \pic["name",draw=black] {angle=b--a--c};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

i first had to update my pgf-package (which i believe i successfully did), because apparently this "angles"-thing is quite new.

now i've looked in a lot of forums and this concept always seemed to work.
for me it also does, but only if i leave out the optional argument `"name"` to label the angle. with this as an argument, as in the code above, i get an error-message that says:

```
> ! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.

> <inserted text>

> \par

> l.44 \pic["name",draw=black]

> {angle=b--a--c};

> I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.

> ...
```

i dont understand this error-message.
what have i done wrong?

i believe the syntax to be ok, because i more or less just copy-pasted the code.

i also updated pgf twice - in admin- and nonadmin-mode, so this should be ok.

also it works if i just leave out that one optional argument of `\pic` (but i would really like to label the angle).

i hope you can help me out here:)

Comment: Your original code has no `\begin{document}` , `\end{document}`. Try with my code given you with editing your code.

Comment: yes, sorry, i forgot that in the question, but that was not the cause of the error

Comment: load also the `babel` library (not the package).

Comment: sorry, how do you mean that? i have `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` in my preambel. when i change for example to `english` it suddenly works. whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

There is no error with TexLive 2013 and Ubuntu 14.04 :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (1,0);
\coordinate (c) at (0,1);
\draw (a)--(b);
\draw (a)--(c);
\pic["name",draw=black] {angle=b--a--c};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i thought so, but for me theres an error. my os is windows 7 (i'm using texmaker, if that is relevant). do you have an idea what could possably cause this?

Comment: As @percusse mentioned above, try `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`

Comment: oooh, thats a thing. i didnt quite understand. thanks!